# sqlsrv_connect not returning object like mysql_connect.it is just returning ResourceId

Tags: php, mysql, sqlsrv

```
I am trying to get data from sqlserver using PHP.
I have connected to the server by using sqlsrv DLLs.
i can able to get the data from server using sqlsrv_query() function.
but i am using the class for executing the queries,
i mean i am not calling queries directly,
instead i using  the following class as follows ,  
   class mssql{
         //function to connect with mssql server
            public function connect(){  
                $serverName = $this->dbhost; //serverName\instanceName
                $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=> $this->dbname, "UID"=> $this->dbuser, "PWD"=> $this->dbpass);
                $this->connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
                return $this->connection;  // here it is returning ResourceId insted object
             }
        //function to excute select qyeury       
            public function query($query, $remember_result=TRUE){
                $result = sqlsrv_query($query, $this->connection);
                return $result;     
             }
    }
```

// i am creating the object for that class 
    $db1 = new mssql($C->DB_HOST, $C->DB_USER, $C->DB_PASS, $C->DB_NAME);
    now i am executing the select query like below using the object,
    $r = $this->db1->query('SELECT * from tblveterinary', FALSE);
          and the problem is it is returning null,
          the problem behind this is the sqlsrv_connect returning resource id ,
          but to perform all the function i need sqlsrv_connect return object.
            please suggest me on this,
          thank you.

Comment: You've got to create this object by yourself. You can't change the return value of [sqlsrv_connect](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php).

Comment: thanks for your reply.When i am using mysql_connect it is returning mysql object,but in this case sqlsrv_connect returning ResourceId only

Comment: Different functions have got different behaviour, that's life. Maybe you want to look into PDO?

Comment: yes,i am not able to create object based on ResourceId,

Comment: I have tried to get object by using sqlsrv_fetch_object,It is working fine for only sqlsrv_query,but it is not working for sqlsrv_connect..
please suggest me to go futher

Comment: Please include the code with the problem.